# How to only sample unmasked pixels in GEE JS API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to sample 1000 pixels in my image. And some pixels of my image are masked according to the slope scale so that I can focus on the valid pixels for me. However, when I use the image.sample function, I find out that it will sample masked pixels which will cause most of the sample pixels are masked. Here is my example code.

```
var cdl = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')).first();
var cdgeometry = cdl.geometry();
// select corn in USA
var cropland = cdl.select('cropland').eq(1);
var confidence = cdl.select('confidence').gte(70);
var AGresult = cdl.updateMask(confidence).updateMask(cropland);
Map.addLayer(AGresult, {}, 'AGresult');

// calculate DEM
var Dem = ee.Image("USGS/3DEP/10m").select('elevation');
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(Dem);
var aspect = ee.Terrain.aspect(Dem);

var S1collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH')) 
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))  
    .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-30')  
    .map(function(img){return img.updateMask(confidence).updateMask(cropland)});
var S1median= S1collection.median().clip(AGRegions.geometry());

var slopemask1 = slope.select('slope').gte(0);
var slopemask2 = slope.select('slope').lte(5);
S1median = S1median.updateMask(slopemask1).updateMask(slopemask2);
Map.addLayer(S1median,{},'S1');

var samples = S1median.sample({
  region: cdgeometry,
  scale: 10,
  numPixels: 1000, 
  seed: 0, 
  geometries: true 
});
print(samples);
```

The imagecollection called AGRegions is included already. How can I make sure that it only sample these unmasked pixels?